# Very very slow wifi after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade

I use a Lenovo G550 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.

WiFi is very very slow after getting 18.04.

What can I do?

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3:


04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:04b5]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo IdeaPad S10e [17aa:3a23]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Hi. I have just edited my question and added the output as requested. thanks.

Comment: Remove `bcmwl-kernel-source` and install `firmware-b43-installer`

Comment: hi. thanks for your reply. which command in terminal do I use to remove

Comment: and which command do I use to install?

Comment: `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer && sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: It did not really improve wifi. Is there anything else I can do (other than going back to ubuntu 16)?